# Set cursor on disabled control

Tags: wpf

During background updates, I want to disable a user control and show a wait cursor above it.

A simple example with just a button and not an entire user control, shows that the Cursor property seems to be ignored by WPF when the control is disabled.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Height="50"/>
        <Button IsEnabled="False" Cursor="Wait" Height="50" />
        <Button Cursor="Wait" Height="50" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Notice that I won't set the for the entire application, Mouse.OverrideCursor won't work.

Comment: I know you can force WPF to [show tooltips even on disabled controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.showondisabled.aspx), but I'm not sure if they have the same thing for cursors.

Answer (score 2):

Set your Cursor on the parent panel, not the individual controls.

For example,

```
<StackPanel Cursor="Wait">
    <Button Height="50"/>
    <Button IsEnabled="False" Height="50" />
    <Button Height="50" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: And if the cursor was only needed for one of the `Button`s, it'd be easy to wrap it in a simple decorator (e.g. `Border`) and set the cursor on that.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it, but a possible workaround can be placing a transperent though enabled `Grid` (or any other "invisible" Control) on top of the disabeld one, and set the `Grid` cursor to `Wait`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Busy Indicator](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator&ei=_ibvTtarMYz48QPoq6CjCg&usg=AFQjCNHkJ-ewqR789_hG-c5Q6cVmFimY5Q&sig2=HiG5uRDdZL61-xPTLeW8OQ) from [WPF toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:extToolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
 <extToolkit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="True" BusyContent="Wait">
   <StackPanel>         
    <Button Height="50"/>               
  </StackPanel> 
 </extToolkit:BusyIndicator>
</Window>
```